# Best way to use static images based on property in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want the image component I create to show a different image based on the prop I pass in. Is there any better/cleaner way to do it than this where I just do a switch statement to see which import should be used based on the prop?

```
import image_1 from './image_1';
import image_2 from './image_2';

function Image(props) {
    let image;
    switch(props.imageName) {
        case('image 1'):
            image=image_1;
            break;
        case('image 2'):
            image=image_2;
            break;
    }

    return (
        <img src={image}>
        </img>
    );
}

export default Image;
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but there are some improvements: 
1) can destruct props in params 
2) should always use default case in switch
3) should not use   if you don't have children inside img

```
const Image = ({imageName}) => {
    let image;

    switch(imageName) {
        case 'image 1' :
            image = image_1;
            break;
        default 'image 2':
            image = image_2;
    }

    return (
        <img src={image} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A case statement works but it gets unwieldy when it's long.

You could define an object with the values of your prop as keys, and the images as the values of those keys. Like so (in ES6 syntax):

```
import image_1 from './image_1';
import image_2 from './image_2';

const images = { 
  foo: image_1,
  bar: image_2,
};

const Image = ({ name }) => ( # name is 'foo'
  <img src={images[name]} />
);

export default Image;
```